# How to get request object in EJS filter?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I would like to get request object in my EJS filter. Is it possible?

My filter is quite simple but I need to see in which area is it fired (by url path) to serve correct assets. I believe I can take url from request but how to get it here?

I started to write middleware function which would set interesting value in the function scope, but it would not work because value can be changed by other request before ejs filter will be fired.

I know I could handle it with domains, but I'm not yet familiar with them and even my node version does not support it.

Is there a simple way to take req object inside ejs filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds that your middleware solution was on the right track, but that you used `app.locals` instead of `res.locals`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.request = req;
  next();
});
```

`app.locals` is an application-wide storage, and would be overwritten by each new request; `res.locals` is uniquely scoped to each request.

If you want to use `request` in your filter, you're still going to have to pass it as an argument:

```
<%=: myvar|myfilter:request %>
```

Obviously, instead of passing the entire request object, you can use just the `.url` property if that's the only thing you need in your filter.

Comment: Hmmm so shuld I put res in to clousre scope and then use it in my filter with res.locals... ?

Comment: @xaoonipu sorry I forgot about how to use it from your filter, I edited my answer.

Comment: Heh - looks like it is the best solution (after your edit) - and I already put everything I wanted in closure ;) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @xaoonipu yes the middleware isn't strictly necessary, unless you want the `request` variable to be available everywhere without having to include it in the `res.render` call each time :)